# How to upgrade my Symfony applications while using flex?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-flex

I found a Symfony component I would like to use in my project but it is only available since the version 5.2 and all my Symfony elements are currently in version 5.1.10.

I read the following links :

- [How to upgrade your Symfony project](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/upgrading.html) (but not a flex one)
- [How to convert your project into a flex one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html)
- This [link](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/575) describing the same issues I'm facing but not giving a proper answer.

But I did not found how to upgrade all my current 5.1.10 version elements to 5.2.

I tried to manualy replace all '5.1.*' occurences in my `composer.json` with '5.2.*' and then run `composer update` but it did not work and throws the following error :

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/symfony 5.2.* exists as symfony/symfony[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.0, v5.1.0-BETA1, v5.1.0-RC1, v5.1.0-RC2, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/framework-bundle v5.2.1 requires symfony/cache ^5.2 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v5.2.0 requires symfony/cache ^5.2 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-bundle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v5.2.0, v5.2.1].
```

Comment: Check the 'extra' section at the bottom of composer.json.  Did you change the 'symfony require' version?

Comment: @Cerad I did not, it seems to work. Thank you. I'm pretty new with php.

Comment: I never had to update that section before so it was new to me as well.  I had gotten the same error as you did so I did my usual composer troubleshooting which consists of creating a new project and then comparing the composer.json files.

Comment: Please share more details. It looks like you are using any configuration that blocks the update

Answer (score 1):

I you want to upgrade a minor version, e.g. from 5.1 to 5.2 you can follow this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html)

> to upgrade to a new minor version, you will probably need to update the version constraint next to each library starting symfony/. Suppose you are upgrading from Symfony 4.3 to 4.4:

```
{
    "...": "...",

    "require": {
-         "symfony/cache": "4.3.*",
+         "symfony/cache": "4.4.*",
-         "symfony/config": "4.3.*",
+         "symfony/config": "4.4.*",
-         "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
+         "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "...": "...",

        "...": "A few libraries starting with
                symfony/ follow their versioning scheme. You
                do not need to update these versions: you can
                upgrade them independently whenever you want",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
    },
    "...": "...",
}
```

> Your `composer.json` file should also have an `extra` block that you will also need to update:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "...": "...",
-         "require": "4.3.*"
+         "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
```

After that you can update your dependencies with:

```
composer update
```